# check and create not exist variables in r

Tags: r

Case by case, variables are existed 'group1' or 'group1', 'group2' or 'group1', group2' 'group3' (these are variable).

However, I want to make three group variables every time.

For example, if I have only one group variable 'group1', but I want to get 'group1', 'group2', and 'group3' ('group2' and 'group3' will be empty column).

[image]

I think it will work checking the variable name and making not exists variables.

Let me know how can I work this.

Comment: Would be great if you could explain it with an example.

Comment: @RonakShah I added example image.

Comment: What do you want the new columns populated with?  They need to have a value, whether it be just `""` or `NA`

Comment: @RichardScriven New columns are just empty.

Comment: There's no such thing as "empty" for a column.  If there's nothing in it we wouldn't need it to be there in the first place. Each row needs a value of some kind.

Comment: @hamel Like Richard Scriven said, columns cannot be empty, they need to contain a value.  Please edit your question to include the code that you've tried already, why it doesn't give you what you want, and what values you want in the new columns.

Comment: @RichardScriven 'group2' and 'group3' have NULL value. My question is sometimes group variable is existed only one or two or three but, I want to always get three group variable. So when I have only one group variable, other groups are created with NULL value.

Comment: @hamel - `NULL` is not a valid column value in a `data.frame`. `df$col <- NULL` will delete it. There are hack-ish ways around this, but just use `NA` instead as a missing value placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

`NA` seems like a reasonable value to fill in for this circumstance:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10,group1=1)

vars <- c("group1","group2","group3")
df[setdiff(vars,names(df))] <- NA

#   id group1 group2 group3
#1   1      1     NA     NA
#2   2      1     NA     NA
#3   3      1     NA     NA
#4   4      1     NA     NA
#5   5      1     NA     NA
#6   6      1     NA     NA
#7   7      1     NA     NA
#8   8      1     NA     NA
#9   9      1     NA     NA
#10 10      1     NA     NA
```

Also works for other combinations...

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:10,group1=1,group2=2)
df[setdiff(vars,names(df))] <- NA

#   id group1 group2 group3
#1   1      1      2     NA
#2   2      1      2     NA
#...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not my question. Not always have 'group1'. Sometimes 'group1' and 'group2' so I have to create 'group3'. I will work this in for loop so I couldn't create not exist variable by using your code.

Comment: @hamel - did you even try the code? It works when you have any possible combination of group1/2/3 pre-existing because of `setdiff()`

Comment: setdiff function can use for elements not column name.

Comment: @hamel - I'm afraid I have no idea what you want then. This answer matches your desired result in the question, and until you can clarify what you want we're all stabbing in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have columns full of `NA` aside from the already filled ones then this works :

```
    cbind(id=1:10,group1=rep(1,10),data.frame(group2=NA,group3=NA))
   id group1 group2 group3
1   1      1     NA     NA
2   2      1     NA     NA
3   3      1     NA     NA
4   4      1     NA     NA
5   5      1     NA     NA
6   6      1     NA     NA
7   7      1     NA     NA
8   8      1     NA     NA
9   9      1     NA     NA
10 10      1     NA     NA
```

If you want an empty dataframe with the appropriate columns then you want to use this:

```
    data.frame(id=integer(),group1=numeric(),group2=numeric(),group3=numeric(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 id     group1 group2 group3
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not my question. Not always have 'group1'. Sometimes 'group1' and 'group2' so I have to create 'group3'. I will work this in for loop so I couldn't create not exist variable by using your code.

Comment: What you want is unclear.